# Select a substring in Oracle SQL after a specific word in the string in certain conditions only

Tags: substring, oracle-sqldeveloper

Follow up from another users post entitled 'How do I Select a substring in Oracle SQL after a specific word in the string?'

I am using Oracle SQL Developer to run my script.

The solution works perfectly in 50% of my scenarios using:

`ltrim(substr(SUMMARY, instr(SUMMARY, 'TEXT:') + length('TEXT:')))  AS Summary`

This works when my system is generating alerts and the string is consistent (always containing 'TEXT:')
However there are instances when manual strings are entered. In those cases I need the whole string/sentence to be in the output.

For example:

| Example | Output |
| --- | --- |
| TEXT: No response from gateway | No response from gateway |
| Follow up from previous incident | ow up from previous incident |

Would anyone know how I can achieve this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to do it conditionally; if text starts with `TEXT:`, remove it and return the rest of message. Otherwise, return the whole message.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'TEXT: No response from gateway'   from dual union all
  3     select 'Follow up from previous incident' from dual
  4    )
```

Query:

```
  5  select col,
  6         case when substr(col, 1, 5) = 'TEXT:' then trim(substr(col, 6))
  7              else col
  8         end result
  9  from test;

COL                              RESULT
-------------------------------- --------------------------------
TEXT: No response from gateway   No response from gateway
Follow up from previous incident Follow up from previous incident

SQL>
```

Comment: both of the solutions work perfectly and are giving the required results

Answer (score 1):

If "TEXT:" always occurs at the start of the string, Littlefoot's Answer is perfect. If not, something like

```
select
     case when instr(SUMMARY, 'TEXT:') = 0 then SUMMARY
          else ltrim(substr(SUMMARY, instr(SUMMARY, 'TEXT:') + length('TEXT:')))
     end result
  from test
```

should do the trick